# minecraft plugin reload config does not work

Tags: java, minecraft

This plugin is about killing hackers but for some reason it will not reload config through command and i have tried everything but nothing, when i change  config i have to reload server not by command.

on other classes the config is set to true / false and when i go to config the config does not save

```
[imports]

public class main extends JavaPlugin {


    public void onEnable() {

        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("HackerFound is online!");

        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveDefaultConfig();
        saveConfig();

        /*           Event Listeners              */

        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new banMsg(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new blockBreak(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new blockPlace(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new itemPickup(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new itemDrop(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new onFlight(this), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new playerHit(this), this);

        /* ************************************   */

    }

    public void onDisable() {

        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("HackerFound is online!");

    }



    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if(cmd.getName().equals("hf")) {
            if(args.length == 0) {
                s.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "/hf reload");
                return false;
            } else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
                if(!s.hasPermission("hf.reload")) {
                    s.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You do not have permission");
                } else {
                    reloadConfig();
                    s.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "HackerFound config has been reloaded!");
                }
                return true;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: this code works fine... the config would be reloaded! Can you show the part in which you want use the values from config?

Comment: right from booleans

Answer (score 0):

```
death_message: '&a&l{player} &c&lhas been found hacking, so he/she will be punished by death!'
ban_message: '&a&l{player} &c&lhas been found hacking, he/she left and now unable to return!'

#from here
block_break_death: true
block_place_death: true
item_drop_death: true
item_pickup_death: true
player_hit_entity_death: true
player_flight_death: true
player_join_ban: true
```